# box2d body shape modification

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, box2d, physics

Is it possible to modify a shape within a body after assigning it, for example I have a box shape for my game hero body, and when I press the down arrow I want my hero to crouch witch means that I need the body shape to be resized.

I've already searched in google but it appears that the topic of modyfing shapes is not so popular. If it's impossible maybe you know a better way of doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's possible without something like replacing the shapes and reattaching them to the body.

My suggestion would be to have two separate bodies, one for the bottom part of the character and one for the top part, connected with a prismatic joint.

(More info on joints [here](http://blog.allanbishop.com/box2d-2-1a-tutorial-part-2-joints/).)

Comment: Yeah, I considered that option, but I want to limit the body number to minimum and I hoped that there's a possibility not documented in the box2d manual.

Comment: What you could do, then, is to have the body consist of two fixtures instead, and reposition the top one in respect to the rest of the body. It would have to be an instantaneous thing rather than an animated effect, and I'm not sure how well it would work physics-wise - I am writing this without testing - but it's the only one-body solution I can think of.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I though but I couldn't move the shape within a body, and I was curious if it's possible to do any transforms on them.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)scaleShape
{
    b2CircleShape shape;

    for (b2Fixture *f = self.yourb2Body->GetFixtureList(); f; f = f->GetNext())
    {
        shape = *(b2CircleShape *)f->GetShape();

        self.yourb2Body->DestroyFixture(f);
        shape.m_radius += 0.01;
        self.yourFixture.shape = &shape;
        self.yourFixture.isSensor = true;
        self.yourb2Body->CreateFixture(&self.yourFixture);
    }
```